# Faster animation on a AVD that emulates OpenGL ES 2.0 support

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-virtual-device

Animation OpenGL has one rate (speed) on a physical device that supports OpenGL ES 3.0 or on AVD with support for OpenGL ES 3.0. But when I run the application on an emulator with OpenGL ES 2.0 support (API 15), the animation speeds up 2-3 times. The choice of various types of rendering (Settings -> Advanced -> OpenGL ES renderer) did not fix the problem - animation is still accelerated or vice versa slow. Question: is it possible to solve this problem?

Note: checked on various AVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a feature of AVD with support for OpenGL ES 2.0. Tried various game applications for OpenGL 2.0/OpenGL 3.0. On physical devices the speed is normal, but on all AVD speed faster and not permanent.